# Does DocuSign need to update their client root certificate checking?

Tags: ssl, docusignapi, lets-encrypt

We use DocuSign Connect, where we have a webhook that gets called by DocuSign. Since October 1st, we have not received any calls to our webhook. On the DocuSign failure log it shows these errors:

`Error - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.; The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`

We have checked and our server is returning the newer Lets Encrypt certificate - ie with `ISRG Root X1`, rather than the older `DST Root CA X3` which expired on Sep 30 2021.

Similar to how Postman had to be updated to accept the newer certificate (https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/10338), it appears DocuSign needs to updated their code to use a more recent client library.

Does this seem correct?

Comment: Hello @nevster, we have the same kind of erreur message on our webhook (only in production) - did you managed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

[DocuSign uses the Microsoft trusted root cert list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/trusted-root/release-notes). So the next question will be when was the LetsEncrypt cert added to the root list.

I've submitted a bug report on your behalf, but please provide your details to help:

Open a case with DocuSign Developer Support so we can actively test with your webhook listener (your server).

Open your case on [contact support](https://support.docusign.com/en/contactSupport).

If you have a production DocuSign account, login (top right corner).

If you don't have a production account, just open the case on the contact support page, at the bottom, using the **DocuSign API's Integration Support** option.

**Important:** reference DocuSign internal bug CONNECT-2630 in your support request.

## PS

Meanwhile, depending on your priority, you could use a $15 server cert from any reputable supplier until the problem is solved.

## Update

DocuSign has confirmed that the new LetsEncrypt root cert needs to be added to the DocuSign front end servers and we're working to have that done.